# Android Activity Toolbar Up Button not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have created an activity to hold fragments. There is no up button displayed in the toolbar when it is run or in the xml preview.

This is the code I used to add the toolbar to the activity

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.category_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Test");
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

I've used all the correct libraries (AppCompatActivity). This Activity holds a fragment and thats were it doesn't show.

XML for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/category_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/toolbar">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've also set the parent activity in the manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".TestActivity"
                  android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
```

Is there anything else I need to add to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: You typically use FrameLayouts for Fragment containers, but nothing immediately seems wrong with this. `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` should be all you need

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, I used the wrong method haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `AppCompatActivity` as base activity, using `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` rather than `setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, would resolve your problem.

`setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` would work if you use `ActionBarActivity.`